# How to send validated object to RabbitMQ in Play 2.5.x with Scala?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, rabbitmq, playframework-2.5

I am using Play 2.5.x to handle HTTP request. The data sent to my server is in JSON format. So play's json library is used like `import play.api.libs.json._`.

My action to handle the request is as follows:

```
def sendItems = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { req =>
  val result = SMSItemObj.readItems(req.body)
  result.fold(
    errors => {
      BadRequest(Json.obj("status" -> "KO", "message" -> JsError.toJson(errors)))
    },
    items => {
      channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, items.getBytes)
      Ok(Json.obj("status" -> "OK"))
    }
  )
}
```

The `SMSItemObj` is defined as follows:

```
case class SMSItem(phone: String, content: String)
object SMSItemObj {
  implicit val smsItemReads: Reads[SMSItem] = (
    (JsPath \ "phone").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "content").read[String]
    )(SMSItem.apply _)

  def readItem(json: JsValue) = json.validate[SMSItem]

  def readItems(json: JsValue) = json.validate[List[SMSItem]]
}
```

However, `items.getBytes` cannot compile, which seems the scala List cannot be converted to java bytes.

I am using `amqp-client 3.6.1`.

```
"com.rabbitmq" % "amqp-client" % "3.6.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to convert your items to a JsArray, then serialize the array to String and finally get the bytes to be sent to rabbitMQ.

With play you can create a Format class that is responsible of reading and writing to Json.

You might also just want to serialize your model using scala serializable or any serialization library and send the bytes to RabbitMQ, but in that case the applications reading from RabbitMQ should have the same models and serializers to be able to read the message.

Enjoy.